# Angular Input get result after click result

Tags: angular

I have a component:

In my .html file

```
<app-mycomp [obj]="myobj" (click)="process()"></app-mycomp>
```

In my .ts file

```
myobj = [];

process() {
    this.myobj.push({ id: 1, name: 'somename' });
}
```

In the app-mycomp html:

```
<div (click)="clickEvent()"></div>
```

In the app-mycomp ts:

```
@Input() obj: any;

clickEvent() {
   alert(JSON.stringify(this.obj));
}
```

The issue is that when I click process() I get a blank alert until I click it a second time...then I get the data I pushed.

I can I fix this so the alert waits until the data has been pushed?

Comment: Easies way just use setTimeout(() => alert(JSON.stringify(this.obj)));

Comment: hello https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf2tg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmycomp%2Fmycomp.component.ts is this way you want ? @wain2021

Comment: @Wain2021 when and how will you call `click()="process()"` ?

Comment: @Wain2021 ... When the user click on the component

Comment: @Wain2021 explain more.. when user clicks on which component ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Almost perfect but BehaviorSubject, Input, Output and Eventemitter is a lot of things happening for one thing?

Comment: @TonyMarko, I want to avoid setTimeouts

Comment: @Wain2021 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf2tg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmycomp%2Fmycomp.component.ts here is updated link. is this working fine now ?